# Is there a Mac FTP client that will open SSH at current location?

Tags: terminal, mac, ssh, iterm, ftp

I often find myself looking at files in an FTP client and I need to do something from the shell. My workflow is to open terminal/iTerm, SSH in to the same server, and navigate to where I need in the file system.

On windows using WinSCP there is a "PuTTY at this location" that I love. Anything similar on Mac? I see Forklift has a launch terminal button but it seems to only work for the local file system.

Answer (score 1):

Try Cyberduck, it should be good.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Cyberduck has "Terminal" item in View>Customize Toolbar that will send the proper ssh example.com command and cd to your current location. Interesting that forklift, for instance, doesn't have the same feature, unless I'm missing something being on the trial.